# Safari: Shortcut to switch between developer window and safari

Tags: safari, development, catalina

In every other application (including Chrome I'm coming from - before the Catalina update) I was able to switch between windows with Cmd + ` (on a German keyboard that is Cmd + >).

Is there a shortcut to switch between an undocked developer window and the safari browser window?

I'm not talking about switching Tabs (I fixed that already :D).

*Update*
I just saw, that I can change FROM browser TO dev window with Cmd.+ ` but not back. (!!? :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch one way: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

Switch the other way: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>

- Replace <kbd>`</kbd> with the necessary language specific equivalent.
- Your solution was very close. Normally the key combination you mentioned loops through available windows. In this specific case you have to return to a previous window by adding <kbd>Shift</kbd>.